# How can I uncompress a zipped archive in Windows using puppet

Tags: zip, puppet, archive, unzip, compression

I have come across this module:

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/counsyl/windows#windowsunzip

However this module only allows you to extract one file at a time. So does anyone know of a way to extract the whole zip archive? For example, I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
unzip { 'SampleUnzipper':
    source => "c:/path/to/zipped/archive/zippedfile.zip",
    dest => "c:/path/to/extracted/folder/",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [staging](https://github.com/nanliu/puppet-staging) module. Since it's a windows node. If you're using `Puppet Enterprise` this module is supplied already but named pe_staging.

Something like this would do:

```
staging::extract { 'SampleUnzipper':
  source  => 'c:/path/to/zipped/archive/zippedfile.zip',
  target  => 'c:/path/to/extracted/folder',
}
```

If your using `Puppet Enterprise` then just replace `staging::extract` with `pe_staging::extract`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm currenlty using puppet open source. This module appears to make use of the "[unzip](https://github.com/nanliu/puppet-staging/blob/master/manifests/extract.pp)" command which gets executed via the exec resource. I think the unzip command belongs to [info-zip](http://www.info-zip.org). I'm afraid this sofware isn't installed on my windows puppet agent. The only other option I can think of is doing the unzipping via powershell. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Didn't even think of there being a software dependency. Sorry about that.